# Angularjs:ng-show taking some time to reflect

Tags: angularjs

I have a search page say 'search_page.html'.I want to show the users 'No record found' message if users click on the search button and no record is found.

Here is the code to display the message:

```
 <div nng-show="list.length==0">
        <span>No record is found</span>            
 </div>

<div  ng-repeat="x in list">
  --showing the record here
</div>
```

When user type something in text box and click on search button then 
"No record is found" is displayed and if search records exist then it disappears after some time and records are displayed.

Can anyone suggest me bettere solution.I want to show the message only if there is no search result exist.

Comment: I have also tried ng-cloak but not working

Answer (score 0):

I would to something like this [demo](http://jsbin.com/qexusebofi/1/edit?html,js,output).

So basically, the thing that made it work is in the `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat='item in vm.filtered = (vm.items | filter: vm.query)'>{{item}}</li>
```

I saved the filtered items so I have a way to check its count, then have the ng-if of the text when the filtered items' count is zero like

```
<div ng-if='vm.filtered.length == 0'>No match found</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this can be done using a tricky code like:

In your controller:

```
$scope.noRecords = false;
Service.getRecord(function(data){
  $scope.list = data.list;
  if($scope.list.length == 0){
    $scope.noRecords = true;
  }
});
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-show="noRecords">
        <span>No record is found</span>            
 </div>

<div  ng-repeat="x in list">
  --showing the record here
</div>
```

That way it should work fine

Comment: Yes this will work definetly.But can we do it not writing any js code.I want to change the code only in html file.As my project is live and I don't wat to change the controller code

Comment: Not possible using a efficient solution. If you can do change the controller then you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have to change the controller and views.
Here is my solution:

**In view :**

```
<div class="divEmpty" id="divNoRecord">
              No record is found
</div>
```

**css:**

```
 .divEmpty {
         display:none;
         text-align:center;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 if ($scope.list.length == 0) {  
    angular.element(document.getElementById('divNoRecord')).show();
 }
 else {

       angular.element(document.getElementById('divNoRecord')).hide();
     }
```